# CodeIgniter does not returns the 2nd procedure result

Tags: sql, rest, codeigniter, procedure

1. I am calling 2 functions from 2 different models from a Rest Controller.
2. Every model function calling procedure.
3. First model function returns the result but second model function does not returns the result. It returns the value of `$query->num_rows()` like 2 rows but not returns `$query->result() or $query->result_array() or $query->result_object()`
4. After calling every procedure in model function, I written `$query->next_result() & $query->free_result()`

but still its not working

First Rest Controller:

```
public function fetchAll_get() {
    $user = $this->validateToken(); //This
    $results = $this->AdminModel->selectAllAdmin($user);
    $this->set_response($results, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Second Rest Controller:

```
public function validateToken() {
        try {
            $token = $this->getBearerToken();
            $payload = JWT::decode($token, SECRETE_KEY, ['HS256']);

            $isUserFound = $this->AuthModel->isUserExists($payload);

            if($isUserFound[0]->Status == "ERROR") {
                $response = array(
                    "Status" => "ERROR",
                    "Message" => "Token is invalid or expired"
                );
                $this->throwError($response);
            } else {
                return $payload;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response = array(
                "Status" => "ERROR",
                "Message" => $e->getMessage()
            );
            $this->throwError($response);
        }
}
```

First Model:

```
public function isUserExists($user)
{
    $sql = 'call usp_IsUserExists(?, ?)';
    $params = array(
        "username" => $user->userId,
        "userType" => $user->userType
    );
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $result = $query->result();

    $query->next_result();
    $query->free_result();

    return $result;
}
```

Second Model:

```
public function selectAllAdmin($user)
{
    $results[] = array();

    $sql = 'call usp_SelectAllAdmin(?)';
    $params = array(
        "createId" => $user->userId
    );
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $result = $query->result();

    $results[0]['data'] = $result;

    $query->next_result();
    $query->free_result();

    return $results;
}
```

Note 1: Transaction not required for both the procedures, both procedure used to retrieve data.

Note 2: `application/config/database.php`

```
   $db['default'] = array(
                          'dbdriver' => 'mysqli'
                     )
```

Note 3: `system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php`

```
function next_result()
{
     if(is_object($this->conn_id))
     {
         return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
     }
}

public function free_result()
{
    if (is_object($this->result_id))
    {
        $this->result_id->free();
        $this->result_id = FALSE;
    }
}
```

First Procedure:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_IsUserExists;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_IsUserExists(
        vUserId varchar(12),
        vUserType varchar(20)
    )
    BEGIN

        DECLARE custom_errors CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22012';
        DECLARE vUserStatus VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE vMessage VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE vUserCount INT DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            SELECT "ERROR" AS Status, "Exception Occurred: Please Try Again!" AS Message;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
            SELECT "ERROR" AS Status, "Warning Occurred: Please Try Again!" AS Message;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR custom_errors
        BEGIN
            SELECT "ERROR" AS Status, vMessage AS Message;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        set time_zone = '+05:30';

        START TRANSACTION;

            IF trim(vUserType) = "Admin" OR trim(vUserType) = "SuperAdmin" OR trim(vUserType) = "SuperSuperAdmin" THEN
                SELECT COUNT(employeeId) INTO vUserCount FROM Admin WHERE employeeId = trim(vUserId);
                SELECT max(status) INTO vUserStatus FROM Admin WHERE employeeId = trim(vUserId);
            ELSEIF trim(vUserType) = "Customer" THEN
                SELECT COUNT(customerId) INTO vUserCount FROM Customer WHERE customerId = trim(vUserId);
                SELECT max(status) INTO vUserStatus FROM Customer WHERE customerId = trim(vUserId);
            ELSE
                SET vMessage = "You are not authorized person for this operation!";
                SIGNAL custom_errors;
            END IF;

            IF (trim(vUserType) != "SuperSuperAdmin" AND trim(vUserType) != "SuperAdmin" AND trim(vUserType) != "Admin" AND trim(vUserType) != "Customer") OR vUserType IS NULL OR vUserStatus != "Active" THEN
                SET vMessage = "You are not authorized person for this operation!";
                SIGNAL custom_errors;
            END IF;

            IF vUserCount <= 0 THEN
                SET vMessage = "User not exists!";
                SIGNAL custom_errors;
            END IF;

            SELECT "SUCCESS" AS Status, 'User Exists!' AS Message;

        COMMIT;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Second Procedure:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_SelectAllAdmin;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SelectAllAdmin(
        vAdminId varchar(12)
    )
    BEGIN

        DECLARE custom_errors CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22012';
        DECLARE vUserType VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE vUserStatus VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE vMessage VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE vAdminCount INT DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            SELECT "ERROR" AS Status, "Exception Occurred: Please Try Again!" AS Message;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
            SELECT "ERROR" AS Status, "Warning Occurred: Please Try Again!" AS Message;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR custom_errors
        BEGIN
            SELECT "ERROR" AS Status, vMessage AS Message;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        set time_zone = '+05:30';

        START TRANSACTION;

            SELECT max(userType) INTO vUserType FROM Admin WHERE employeeId = trim(vAdminId);
            SELECT max(status) INTO vUserStatus FROM Admin WHERE employeeId = trim(vAdminId);

            IF (trim(vUserType) != "SuperSuperAdmin" AND trim(vUserType) != "SuperAdmin") OR vUserType IS NULL OR vUserStatus != "Active" THEN
                SET vMessage = "You are not authorized person for this operation!";
                SIGNAL custom_errors;
            END IF;

            SELECT count(*) INTO vAdminCount FROM Admin WHERE userType = "Admin";

            IF vAdminCount = 0 THEN
                SET vMessage = "Admin does not found!";
                SIGNAL custom_errors;
            END IF;

            SELECT id, employeeId, userType, lastName, firstName, middleName, gender, dob, maritalStatus, mobile, password, address, city, state, email, pincode, panCard, aadharCard, accountHolderName, bankName, branchName, accountType, accountNumber, ifsc, nomineeName, nomineeMobile, nomineeDOB, nomineeRelation, governmentIdUrl, panCardUrl, bankChequeUrl, profilePhotoUrl, joiningDate, createId, createDate, updateId, updateDate
            FROM Admin
            WHERE userType = "Admin"
            ORDER BY id;

        COMMIT;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```